# Set multiple values for attribute

Tags: javascript, html, rel

It's easy to set attribute for a given element:

`el.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');`

But for some attributes, such as `rel` in the example, multiple values are allowed. In case of `rel`, its values should be [separated by space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel). Therefore, I cannot just `setAttribute`, because that would replace the existing value. What's the right way to *append* value to an existing attribute, so that it'll contain the both values, such as `rel="external nofollow"`? Is there anything better than getting the existing attribute and `+=` the new value?

Note: Ideally, I don't want to use jQuery, just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Nope, you'd have to get the current and add. `var current = el.getAttribute("rel"); el.setAttribute("rel", current += " new stuff");`

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
el.setAttribute("rel", el.getAttribute("rel") + " newRel");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rel` for the `el`, so in addition to the other answer(s) you can use:

`el.setAttribute('rel', el.rel + 'new_rel');`